# How to update attribute frontend labels programmatically?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have the code:

```
 $attributeModel = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute::class)->load($id);
```

And I have to create/update frontend labels of `$attributeModel` for another stores (French & German)

Or maybe I should use another methods?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, it will change  default label

> ```
> $attributeModel = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
>       ->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute::class)->load(140);
>
>   $attributeModel->setData('frontend_label',{Your_value});
>   $attributeModel->save();
> ```

**For  store wise label set**

```
$currentdata= $attributeModel->getStoreLabels();
$currentdata[{StoreID}] = {New Label for store};
$attributeModel->setData('store_labels',$currentdata);
$attributeModel->save();
```

Comment: It works fine! But how to update the label for another store?

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: okay, i will look

Comment: where I should put this code. I want to change attribute label "XYZ" to "Abc" for everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

```
  $attributeModel = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute::class)
    ->load($id);
  $storeLabels = $attributeModel->getStoreLabels();
  $storeLabels[$storeId] = $labelTitle;
  $attributeModel->setStoreLabels($storeLabels);

  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
     ->get($attributeModel->getResourceName())
     ->save($attributeModel);
```

Comment: ha ha.  you have first

Answer (score 0):

On Magento 2.4.2 this works:

```
$attribute = $this->attributeFactory->create()->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
$storeLabels = [
    0 => $attribute->getDefaultFrontendLabel(),
    1 => 'Updated name on store PL',
    2 => 'Updated name on store DE'
];

$attribute->setData('frontend_label', $storeLabels);
$this->productAttributeRepository->save($attribute);
```

Check `_beforeSave` method on `vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/Entity/Attribute.php`

```
     * Validate attribute data before save
     *
     * @param EntityAttribute|AbstractModel $object
     * @return $this
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _beforeSave(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        $frontendLabel = $object->getFrontendLabel();
        if (is_array($frontendLabel)) {
            $this->checkDefaultFrontendLabelExists($frontendLabel, $frontendLabel);
            $object->setFrontendLabel($frontendLabel[0])->setStoreLabels($frontendLabel);
        } else {
            $this->setStoreLabels($object, $frontendLabel);
        }
        $attribute->setData('frontend_label', $storeLabels);
        $this->productAttributeRepository->save($attribute);
```